# "über Jahre" vs "über Jahre hinweg"

Tags: vocabulary

Gibt es einen Unterschied in den Bedeutungen zwischen den Folgenden:

> Über Jahre hatte er sich mit ihr getroffen.
> Über Jahre hinweg hatte er sich mit ihr getroffen.

Oder kann das "hinweg" auch einfach ausgelassen werden?

Comment: Kannst du etwas mehr Kontext angeben? Intuitiv würde ich sagen, wenn man das "hinweg" weglässt, tönt es umgangssprachlich. Wenn's kurz sein soll: "Jahrelang".

Comment: Grammatik ist die Kunst, Wörter zu ganzen Sätzen zusammenzufügen. Wenn keine ganzen Sätze vorliegen, kann man eigentlich gar nichts sagen. Hier fehlt ganz einfach der Kontext.

Comment: Ich stimme dafür diese Frage zu schließen, weil hier der Kontext fehlt. Die Frage sollte umgeschrieben werden. Wenn die Wortgruppe in einen ganzen Satz eingebettet wird, kann sie beantwortet werden.

Comment: Ich hoffe, die Frage ist jetzt mit diesem Beispielsatz klar genug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wenn das gehobene "hinweg" eingefügt ist, verleiht es der Angabe, wie lange sich die beiden getroffen hatten, etwas mehr Gewicht. Das für sich genommen redundante "hinweg" setzt eine Betonung.

Wäre das schon ein Bedeutungsunterschied? Wenn nicht, antworte ich mit Nein.

Als Füllwort kann es auch den Rhythmus des Satzes verändern und ihn verständlicher oder besser sprechbar machen.

Answer (score 1):

In der Bedeutung sehe ich keinen Unterschied

"Über Jahre hinweg" ist ein bisschen sorgfältiger, aber das Wort *hinweg* ist auch ein bisschen papieren oder staubig.

Einem Rapper würde "hinweg" wohl nicht über die Lippen kommen, aber in einem Gerichtsdokument oder Roman klingt es normal und auch nicht veraltet.